# Android ConstraintLayout baseline constraint not visible

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

Learning `ConstraintLayout` and running into this issue where the baseline constraint handle does not become visible even as a text view is selected.

Using `Android Studio 3.4.1`, `Show All Constraints` is selected.

[image]

**gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 28
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

1. In the visual editor select the wanted TextView.
2. Right-click on it.
3. Select "Show Baseline"

Comment: Thanks Kerbel. I wondering why In my Editor Hover over it is not giving that option. Studio version is 3.5

Comment: Is there any shortcut key?

Answer (score 0):

Hover over the visual editor and click on the component to select. There you will see an "ab" button. Click on that.

Comment: You're right only for older versions of Android Studio, in the newer versions you'll have to right-click the TextView and select "Show Baseline".